# Render Items from useState Hook React

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

I have made a call to my api using `useEffect` and stored the array of items using `useState` hook but I'm finding it difficult to render those items into a custom component which will also have the data passed.

Here's my react snippets:

```
export default function CreateCast() {

 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const [bibleCastItems, setBibleCastItems] = useState([]);

 const classes = useStyles();

 const fabStyle = {
   bottom: 50.0,
   right: 30.0,
   position: "fixed"
 };

 useEffect(()=>{
   async function fetchData(){
    var items = await APIService.getAllBibleCasts();
    // console.log(items);
    // console.log(items.data.bibleCasts);
    setBibleCastItems([items.data.bibleCasts]); 
    // items.data.bibleCasts.length > 0 ? setBibleCastItems([items.data.bibleCasts]) 
    // : setBibleCastItems([]);
  }
  fetchData();
  }, []
);

// console.log('bibleCastItems length ' + bibleCastItems.length);

return (
  <GridContainer>
    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
      <Card plain>
        <CardHeader plain color="primary">
         <div className={classes.container}>
           <div className={classes.left}>
           <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>All BibleCasts</h4>
           <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
             Powered by our friends from <b>Unicorn Tech Consultants</b>{" "}
           </p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </CardHeader>
       <CardBody>
         {
           bibleCastItems.map((item, index) => <CastItem key={index} bibleCast={item[index]}/>) // this is where I'm facing issue
           // bibleCastItems.map((item, index) => {
            // console.log(item);
            // setMyItem(item);
            // return <div key={index}>{index}</div>
          // })
        }
        <div className={classes.right}>
            <Fab style={fabStyle} onClick={handleClickOpen}>
              <AddIcon />
            </Fab>
            <UploadFormDialog 
              open={open}
              handleClose={handleClose}
            />
        </div>           
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  </GridItem>
 </GridContainer>
);

function handleClickOpen(){
  setOpen(true);
};

function handleClose(){
  setOpen(false);
};

}
```

Here's my state from browser view:
[![state view][1]][1]

How do I map this state to be a list of components? I'm confused about it

As you can see, I'm using a dialog to create new items and close the dialog once the request is successful. I have one doubt here, how do I tell the main component hosting the dialog that the new data has been fetched and should be added to the state?

My main question here is how to map the items in state to return a list of `<CastItem />` component

CastItem Component Snippet

```
export default function CastItem(props) {

let {bibleCast} = props;

const classes = useStyles();

return <GridContainer>
    <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
        <Card>
            <CardHeader color="info" stats icon>
                <CardIcon color="info">
                    <Streams />
                </CardIcon>
            </CardHeader>

            <CardBody>
                <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>{bibleCast.title}</h3>
                <p className={classes.cardCategory}> Reinhard Bonnke</p>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    </GridItem>
</GridContainer>
}

CastItem.propTypes = {
  bibleCast: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

JSON Response from API in console:

```
[![json response][2]][2]
```

If you were to create a state variable to represent this response as a list and display that list, how would you go about it, using hooks. Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkthN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hf11.png

Comment: You can use a callback to send data from child to parent component , are you familiar with it ?

Comment: Share a snippet and how do I render the state values?

Comment: okay , I will share a code sandbox

Comment: I have added the example , refer it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistake you are doing is in CreateCast component , form api you are already getting an array again you are passing it inside an array, so it is coming as nested array

Do like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
   async function fetchData(){
    var items = await APIService.getAllBibleCasts();
    setBibleCastItems(items.data.bibleCasts); 
  }
  fetchData();
  }, []
);
```

For Maping do like this

```
{
           bibleCastItems.map((item, index) => <CastItem key={index} bibleCast={item}/>) 
        }
```

// For question how to update parent from child follow below

There are two ways you can set data in a parent component , one is refetch from the api or pass from children to parent and update the state there

I have an example here how to update parent and children,to add names to a list,name list state is maintained in parent component here and child will pass back value to parent by adding name

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(["ram"]);

  const handleAddName = (name) => {
    if (name) {
      setList([name, ...list]);
  // or you can refetch the list from api here

    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ float: "left" }}>
        <h1>I am a parent Component</h1>
        <ul>
          {list &&
            list.map((item) => {
              return <li key={item}>{item}</li>;
            })}
        </ul>
      </div>

      <Child handleSubmit={handleAddName} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Child(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const updateNameList = (name) => {
    if (name) {
      props.handleSubmit(name);
      //reset field after data is sent
      // you can also save data here making post request respective api
      setName("");

    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
      <h1>I am a Child Component</h1>
      <p> Add names below</p>
      <br />
      <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => updateNameList(name)}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

refer to this codesand box

[image: Edit naughty-hugle-bdt7k]

Comment: Thanks I have seen it. My issue for now is how to map my state to return a list of components. It seems to be nested. Please take a look at the picture in the question

Comment: What are you trying to achieve , do you want me to show you how to build a component so that you can pass data to it and display the nested data ?

Comment: That would be call but what I really need is to display the items from the api call in my useState list. The map function is only returning one value maybe cos I didnt set the state properly or I'm not mapping the state well. I have a snapshot of the state in an image attached to the question

Comment: Got it can you add your CastItem component how it looks

Comment: Alright. Adding that and the api response from console too

Comment: Check, the response is the second image

Comment: Thanks but it's showing cannot read property map of undefined on this line bibleCastItems.map((item, index) => <CastItem key={index} bibleCast={item}/>)

Comment: It shows only one item in the list when I re-insert "[]" in my useState call like : const [bibleCastItems, setBibleCastItems] = useState([]); instead of const [bibleCastItems, setBibleCastItems] = useState();

Comment: Seen my mistake. Reading too many blogs and less sleep. Thank you so much Goutham sir